# MVC Passing data to a view

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to give `delete post` ability to user who is signed in and his/her `ID` is the same as `userId` in the post. there are 2 `controllers` `Account` that is responsible for user login and `post` `controller`.
When creating a new post this is how I get the `userId` inside the create action in post controller:

```cs
var user_id = userManager.GetUserId(HttpContext.User);
```

In the post details section there are 2 buttons `Edit` and `Delete`

I was thinking to use an `if-else` to hide the buttons but I don't know how to access the `userId`

```cs
@if (signInManager.IsSignedIn(User) && Model.Item.userId == ??)
{
    <div class="card-footer text-center">
        <a asp-action="edit" asp-controller="home" class="btn btn-primary" asp-route-id="@Model.Item.Id">Edit</a>
        <form method="post" asp-action="DeleteUser" asp-route-id="@Model.Item.Id">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
        </form>
    </div>
}
```

Should I create a `Cookie`, or can I use `UserManager` in some ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to achieve that , for example you can read the userid in controller and set viewbag to keep the value . Or you can directly get the user id in razor by :

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager

@if (signInManager.IsSignedIn(User) && Model.Item.userId == @UserManager.GetUserId(User))
```

Or :

```
@using System.Security.Claims;
@if (signInManager.IsSignedIn(User) && Model.Item.userId == @User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier))
```